# converting from javascript to typescript: referencing "this" to window instead of class

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am working on [this authorization code](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/).
Original code snippet can be found by starting from line:

> To do so add new file named “authInterceptorService.js” under
>   “services” folder and paste the code below:

This is javascript version:

```
 angular.module('eucngts').factory('AuthInterceptorService', ['$q', '$location', function ($q, $location) {   
        var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {};

        var _responseError = function (rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 401) {
                localStorage.removeItem('authorizationData');
                $location.path('/login');
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }

        authInterceptorServiceFactory.responseError = _responseError;

        return authInterceptorServiceFactory;
    }]);
```

And this is TypeScript version:

```
module Services {
    export class AuthInterceptorService {
        $location: ng.ILocationService;
        $q: ng.IQService;

        constructor($location, $q) {
            var self = this;
            self.$location = $location;
            self.$q = $q;

        }

        public responseError(rejection) {
            var self = this;// "this" REFERENCES TO WINDOW INSTEAD OF AuthInterceptorService CLASS
            if (rejection.status === 401) {
                localStorage.removeItem('authorizationData');
                self.$location.path('/login');
            }
            return self.$q.reject(rejection);
        }

        static AuthInterceptorServiceFactory($location, $q) {    
            return new AuthInterceptorService($location, $q);
        }


    }

    AuthInterceptorService.$inject = ['$location', '$q'];
    angular.module('eucngts').factory('AuthInterceptorService', AuthInterceptorService.AuthInterceptorServiceFactory);
}
```

In TypeScript version as mentioned in comment above code snippet:

```
var self = this;// "this" REFERENCES TO WINDOW INSTEAD OF AuthInterceptorService CLASS
```

What should I do that I can successfully call `self.$location.path('/login');`
At the moment I receive `Cannot read property 'path' of undefined` error

Comment: Depending on how this is being invoked, the context might be lost. So seeing the other end, which utilizes `AuthInterceptorService` would help. One way to ensure that the context stays is to use Typescript's arrow functions. Something like `public responseError = (rejection) => {...}`  (Source: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript#user-content-use-instance-functions )

Comment: This answers my question @DRobinson . Could you make it answer then I accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how the function is being invoked, the context might be lost. As is the case in standard Javascript, though there's a chance that some of Typescripts abstractions made it easier. As such, seeing the other end, which utilizes AuthInterceptorService would help.

One way to ensure that the context stays is to use Typescript's arrow functions.

```
public responseError = (rejection) => {
    var self = this;// "this" REFERENCES TO WINDOW INSTEAD OF AuthInterceptorService CLASS
    if (rejection.status === 401) {
        localStorage.removeItem('authorizationData');
        self.$location.path('/login');
    }
    return self.$q.reject(rejection);
}
```

(Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript#user-content-use-instance-functions )

Remember that, while this solves some problems, it has downsides as well and isn't for every scenario - the above source spells out a few of these.